# Exponential Curve Fitting with Python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, logistic-regression, curve-fitting

I need some some help regarding curve_fit function of scipy.

```
origin_y = array([ 6.366,  6.548,  6.734,  6.924,  7.118,  7.315,  7.517,  7.723,
    7.932,  8.146,  8.365,  8.587,  8.814,  9.045,  9.281,  9.521,
    9.765, 10.01 , 10.27 , 10.53 , 10.79 , 11.06 , 11.33 , 11.61 ,
   11.89 , 12.18 , 12.47 , 12.77 , 13.07 , 13.38 , 13.69 , 14.01 ,
   14.34 , 14.67 , 15.   , 15.34 , 15.69 , 16.04 , 16.4  , 16.76 ,
   17.13 , 17.51 , 17.89 , 18.28 , 18.67 , 19.07 , 19.48 , 19.89 ,
   20.31 , 20.74 , 21.17 , 21.61 , 22.05 , 22.5  , 22.96 , 23.43 ,
   23.9  , 24.38 , 24.87 , 25.37 , 25.87 , 26.38 , 26.9  , 27.42 ,
   27.95 , 28.49 , 29.04 , 29.6  , 30.16 , 30.74 , 31.32 , 31.91 ,
   32.51 , 33.12 , 33.73 , 34.36 , 35.   , 35.64 , 36.3  , 36.97 ,
   37.64 , 38.33 , 39.03 , 39.74 , 40.46 , 41.2  , 41.95 ])



    origin_x = ([10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96])
```

#Simple Poly Fit

```
log_x_data = np.log(origin_x)
log_y_data = np.log(origin_y)

curve_fit = np.polyfit(origin_x, log_y_data, 1)
print(curve_fit)
```

#My Result
#[0.02170385, 1.71716332]

```
y = np.exp(0.02170385) * np.exp(1.71716332*origin_x)
```

The fitted curve is just a parallel to x axis.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: You aren't even using [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) from scipy.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculus is correct but the coefficients are inverted in

y = np.exp(0.02170385) * np.exp(1.71716332*origin_x)

which sould be

y = np.exp(1.71716332) * np.exp(0.02170385 *origin_x)

[image]

NOTE :

An even better fit is obtained with an equation of this form :

y = a + b * exp( c * x )

The "data curve" and the "computed curve" are quite indistinguishable from each other.

[image]

Comment: THank you, that helps a lot. But I have another question. If I use your suggestion my results is:

log_x_data = np.log(origin_x)
log_y_data = np.log(origin_y)
​
curve_fit = np.polyfit(origin_x, log_y_data, 2)

My Result coefficient are: 
[-6.06298721e-05  2.81306170e-02  1.58509125e+00]

Which is completely wrong...?

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand   log_x_data = np.log(origin_x) log_y_data = np.log(origin_y) ​ curve_fit = np.polyfit(origin_x, log_y_data, 2) . This is hieroglyphical for me. Why don't you first define your equation model on classical form , for example y = a + b * exp( c * x ) . Then translate it into your sotware language ? Anyways the function that you chose seems not at all what I suggest in my main answer.